# Chmod u-x isn't changing anything and I have no idea why

Tags: permissions, chmod

I'm a user on a Debian machine. When I create a file in my home directory, the default permissions appear to be 700, even though umask returns 0022:

```
eulerz@foo:~$ touch testing
eulerz@foo:~$ ls -l testing 
-rwx------ 1 eulerz users 0 2012-03-15 19:34 testing
```

In addition, when I create a file in the tmp directory, it doesn't show up as executable, but it does when I move it to my home directory:

```
eulerz@foo:~$ touch /tmp/made_in_tmp
eulerz@foo:~$ ls -l /tmp/made_in_tmp 
-rw-r--r-- 1 eulerz users 0 2012-03-15 19:39 /tmp/made_in_tmp
eulerz@foo:~$ mv /tmp/made_in_tmp ~
eulerz@foo:~$ ls -l /u/eulerz/made_in_tmp 
-rwxr--r-- 1 eulerz users 0 2012-03-15 19:39 /u/eulerz/made_in_tmp
```

and, of course, chmod doesn't change this:

```
eulerz@foo:~$ chmod -v u-x made_in_tmp 
mode of `made_in_tmp' changed to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
eulerz@foo:~$ ls -l /u/eulerz/made_in_tmp 
-rwxr--r-- 1 eulerz users 0 2012-03-15 19:39 /u/eulerz/made_in_tmp
```

What the heck?
Why is this happening? Where is it telling my home directory "set new things as u+x NO MATTER WHAT"?

And this just started happening recently; the older files in my home directory don't have this problem (but I made a copy of one and it did.)

Comment: What type of filesystem is your home directory on: what does `df ~` show? and `mount | grep ~`?

Comment: @Gilles It's presumably an 'Isilon' network system as its name starts with storage.isilon . ~ isn't mentioned in 'mount' but the drive is /ifs/u on /u type nfs (rw,nodev,noatime,hard,intr,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,tcp,nfsvers=3,addr=10.21.2.115)

ETA: And I see that /tmp is on /dev/sda1 which is presumably a local drive.

Comment: This is [NFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System_%28protocol%29). The server is behaving bizarrely, I don't know why. Can you ask your system administrators?

Comment: @Gilles Thanks for the suggestion, I could in fact open a ticket. I know they have upgraded their storage infrastructure within the past few months, so that may have something to do with it.

Comment: Do an "ls -ln" and an "id" to see if the uid of the "eulerz" who owns the file and the "eulerz" who is logged into the machine is the same.

Comment: Oh, and "ls -ld ~" couldn't hurt either to see what the permissions on the home directory are.

Comment: @PaulTomblin Yes, the uid of the files matches my id; and home directory permissions are drwx------ . @ Gilles I've written to my sysadmins; we'll see what they say whenever they get back to me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The helpdesk got back to me and explained that it's due to the merging of Windows NTFS permissions with regular POSIX permissions, since the Isilon is configured to be accessible by both NFS and [CIFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIFS). So removing the CIFS access would fix the permissions issue.